# How to use Wireshark in live mode via SSHFS

Tags: ssh, wireshark, packet-capture

I have a remote machine that I run experiments on. On this machine, I want to sniff the packets sent and received. On the machine in front of me, I want to open Wireshark and see the packets live.

The only way I have to access the remote machine is SSH.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Establish an SSH-mount using SSHFS.
2. Make sure that `stdbuf` is available (using homebrew on OS X or Cygwin on Windows).
3. Start capturing on the remote machine using

   stdbuf -o0 sudo ibdump -s -o - > sniffer.pcap
4. Run Wireshark on the client

   stdbuf -o0 tail -c +0 -F /sshfsmount/sniffer.pcap | ./Wireshark.exe -k -i -